# Possible to get name of current class from an uninstantiated object in PHP?

Tags: php

I know you can use get_class($this) normally but I need to get the name of the class in a static function where the object hasn't been instantiated.

See the following code:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    static function getClassName()
    {
        echo get_class($this); // doesn't work unless the object is instantiated.
    }
}

$test1 = new ExampleClass();
$test1->getClassName(); // works

ExampleClass::getClassName(); // doesn't work
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question to read that you understand that $this has no meaning in the static case - I think some people might simply think you don't understand what '$this' means.

See my answer about get_called_class, as well.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're looking for the get_called_class() function, if you wish to get the class name from a static method.

See [get_called_class documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out you can use __CLASS__ to get the class name.  Example:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    static function getClassName()
    {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that __CLASS__ will return the class where the function is defined. If you extend it, you won't get the subclass.

Comment: @troelskn: could very well bite the asker in the ass. You should submit this as an answer too so more people see it.

Answer (score 0):

My question is, how are you managing to call a static function without knowing the class name in the first place?

The only two ways I can think of are:

```
ExampleClass::getClassName(); //Hard Coded - the class name is hard and visible
$class = "ExampleClass";
$class::getClassName();       //Soft Coded - the class name is the value of $class
```

Perhaps a better solution could be offered if we knew the context in which you are trying to make the call?

Comment: I'm calling an inherited class and there is a switch() statement in the parent class that requires the class name to decide what to do

Comment: What is the variable data from which you are trying to switch that would require a static function?