# How to get the class name of an uninstantiated class (outside the class)?

Tags: php, class, oop, object

In a config file I want to define a list of classes that can be instantiated at a later time, for example a list of classes used to validate input:

```
// Config file
abstract class Config {
  public static $validators = array(
    FooValidator,
    BarValidator,
  );
}

// Validation at later time
function validate_input($input){
  foreach (Config::$validators as $validatorClassName){
    $validator = new $validatorClassName();
    $result = $validator->validate($input);
    // Do stuff with result
  }
}
```

I know that you can use `__CLASS__` or `get_called_class()` as pointed out in [Possible to get name of current class from an uninstantiated object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476763/possible-to-get-name-of-current-class-from-an-uninstantiated-object-in-php), but those only work inside the class.

A workaround would be to define a constant in each class, like:

```
class FooValidator {
  const CLASS_NAME = __CLASS__;
  public function validate($input){
    // Validate $input
  }
}
```

and then define the list as

```
abstract class Config {
  public static $classes = array(
    FooValidator::CLASS_NAME,
    BarValidator::CLASS_NAME,
  );
}
```

I'd like to avoid doing that, however, because it adds a point of failure that's not intuitive to other developers looking through my code.

Why don't I just use a list of class string names you ask? Mainly because I want PHP to fail the moment `Config` is loaded (with a non-existant validator class), rather than only when `validate_input()` is called.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's impossible to instantiate abstract.

Comment: So you want to instantiate each and every available class? You'll probably need to somehow mark those classes you want to create objects of. If you need a list of available classes then have a look at `get_declared_classes ()`.

Comment: Which version of php you use?

Comment: No, I want to instantiate the list of classes defined in the `Config` file class. The `Config` class file is meant to be non-instantiable/static (hence why it's abstract). PHP version is 5.6.

Comment: Updated the question with an example that should explain what I want to achieve a bit more clearly.

Comment: It's intentional - the point of the question was to find a way to write that test array without string literals for the class names (because those won't generate an error at "compile time" if the classes are missing/have been renamed).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that i correctly understood your question, but maybe you are looking to something like this (**PHP >= 5.5**):

```
<?php

namespace Configs;

class Foo {}
class Bar {}

class Config {
  public static $classes = array(
    Foo::class,
    Bar::class,
  );
}

var_export(Config::$classes);
```

Will print:

```
array (
  0 => 'Configs\\Foo',
  1 => 'Configs\\Bar',
)
```

Comment: I came across `::class` as well, but it seems like you can just type whatever followed by `::class` and it'll be valid code, for example `NonexistantClass::class`.

Comment: Yep, you're right, but you can before create new instance check class with `class_exists` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reflection` class for this...

#### code:

```
// Config file
abstract class Config {
  public static $validators = array(
    'FooValidator',
    'BarValidator',
  );
}

// Validation at later time
function validate_input($input){
  foreach (Config::$validators as $validatorClassName){
    $validator = new $validatorClassName();
    $result = $validator->validate($input);
    // Do stuff with result
  }
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Config');
$staticProperties = $reflection->getStaticProperties();

foreach ($staticProperties as $name => $value) {
    var_dump($name, $value);
}
```

#### output:

```
string 'validators' (length=10)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'FooValidator' (length=12)
  1 => string 'BarValidator' (length=12)
```